# How do I open an html file included in my browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having some weird trouble with opening a simple html file I have included in my extension.
I can open the HTML page with browserAction for example, but anything else does not work.

I tried setting it as an options ui

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "form.html",
    "open_in_tab": true,
    "browser_style": true,
    "chrome_style": true
  },
```

and then I tried to run `runtime.openOptionsPage()` but I'm getting an error

`openOptionsPage() is not a function`

Ok, so the next thing I tried is to simply open a new tab with `window.open`

```
window.open(addon.extension.getURL('form.html'))
```

It opens a tab, but sadly I get the message that the file is blocked

```
iheelllncchdclcmfojmeajmcdolpjdf is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension. Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

I'm out of ideas now. I can't really find anything about any specific permissions I need for me to do this. It also seems nobody has encountered the "is not a function" error, which is probably the weirdest thing about this all.

Anyone knows what I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/

> Web-accessible resources are files inside an extension that can be accessed by web pages or other extensions. [...]
>
> **By default no resources are web accessible;** only pages or scripts loaded from an extension's origin can access that extension's resources. Extension authors can use the web_accessible_resources manifest property to declare which resources are exposed and to what origins.

> These resources are available in a webpage via the URL chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH], which can be generated with the runtime.getURL method. The resources are served with appropriate CORS headers, so they're available via mechanisms like XHR.
>
> **A navigation from a web origin to an extension resource will be blocked unless the resource is listed as web accessible.**

Assuming that your extension is adding link pointing to extension itself then you must explicitly add following policy in manifest:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "form.html"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*" // ...probably more strict than this
      ]
    }
  ],
  // ... rest of manifest
}
```